# Serve postscript outlines like typekit

Tags: postscript, webfonts, typekit

Typekit now serve postscript outlines for some of their fonts. This makes the font render better on windows. If I compare say museo500 that I've hosted and the typekit version, theirs is MUCH better to my eyes.

http://blog.typekit.com/2011/09/15/improved-windows-rendering-for-more-typekit-fonts/

Has anyone replicated this themselves on their own hosted fonts? I took a look at font-forge which looks as though it could convert a Truetype font to PostScript but I thought I'd ask and see if anyone had any advice/suggestions before committing to the time. - hope that's OK! I'll post back here with any information I get.

Comment: I have fond this Page: http://blog.wax-o.com/2012/11/font-face-rendering-problem-in-chrome-and-firefox-use-postscript-outlines/ Maybe a help?

Comment: That looks VERY useful. I'll take a closer look when I get time and post something back here.

Comment: Manaded to have a closer look and this does indeed give a method of doing what I'd like to. It needs more testing but could come in really handy - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's been years since you asked this question, and it deserves an answer. But I'm not clear exactly what you are asking. I'll try multiple interpretations.

The one sentence that is actually a question is, "Has anyone replicated this themselves on their own hosted fonts?" It's not clear to me which concept "this" refers to.

If you are asking, "has anyone written code to serve OpenType fonts in the form of PostScript outlines to Windows GDI computers", I'm pretty confident that very few people will answer "yes" to that question. Serving OpenType fonts the way TypeKit does is very complex. I know, I used to work for the part of Adobe Systems that wrote such code.

If you are asking, "has any content publisher compared the quality of content formatted with OpenType fonts they already serving themselves with the quality of  the same content formatted with comparable fonts served by TypeKit", I imagine by now the answer is "yes, many", but that the people who could answer that are content authors who don't hang out on a programming site like Stack Overflow.

If you are asking, "has any font developer who currently publishes their font designs as OpenType fonts with TrueType outlines converted to OpenType fonts with PostScript outlines, and compared the quality of those served by TypeKit with the original fonts served some other way"…. Again, the answer is probably, "yes". Maaaybe you will find those font developers on Stack Overflow. They are more likely to be on a more font-centric site.

I hope one of those interpretations matches what you were actually asking. And now, this question is no longer unanswered.